# best practice for load multiple style for multiple language in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, webpack, sass

i create a `SPA` with `Angular` .

i my website i have tow language `English` & `Persian` :

**English :** `ltr` and **Persian :** `rtl` .

some times some times in my website need to set custome style for `rtl` and `ltr` .

for example for `lrt` i need set `border-left` for div and for that need to set `border-right` in `rtl` .

i have more this issue in my project .

i want to use the best practice for load styles general and load custome style by chosen language .

**please tell me the best practice for doing this . . .**

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

create two styles files.

for example: `styles-rtl.scss` and `styles-ltr.scss`

create a renderer in your app component for html tag:

You should inject it in your constructor:

```
constructor(private translationService: TranslateService, rootRenderer: RendererFactory2
  ) {
    this.renderer = rootRenderer.createRenderer(document.querySelector('html'), null);
  }
```

When language changes, set `dir` attribute to your html tag:

```
this.translationService.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(
          document.querySelector('html'), 'dir', (event.lang == 'fa') ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'
        );
    });
```

Then in your styles.scss import relative scss file:

```
[dir = 'rtl'] {
  @import "styles-rtl";
}

[dir = 'ltr'] {
  @import "styles-ltr";
}
```

There are other ways to create multi language app, but I found this way more efficient.

Another way is to create two separate app for each language in your `angualr.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

add a class to the body tag depending on the language

```
<body class="ltr">
```

or

```
<body class="rtl">
```

then in css

```
.ltr .my-div {
    border-left: 20px;
}
.rtl .my-div {
    border-right: 20px;
}
```